# Dynamic naming of uploaded files based on a condition

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am uploading images in a Django application. This is my models.py.

```
def file_rename(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    count = Count.objects.get(pk=1)
    ZSN = "ZT-WJ-" + str(count.jeans_count + 1)
    filename = '{}.{}'.format(ZSN, ext)
    return os.path.join('images', filename)

class Images(models.Model):
    design_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=file_rename)
    cost_price = models.FloatField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
```

Here all the uploaded images are being stored with names as `'ZT-WJ-' + count_of_image`. But I don't want `'ZT-WJ-'` to be static. I want it to be based on the category to which the image belongs.
For example can I write some code in the file_rename method like this?

```
if Image.category == "random":
    #
else:
    #
```

How do I do this without interfering with the front-end and not using JavaScript?

Comment: Wouldn't that make it very unstable? Imagine that the user later changes the category of an image, then you need to rename the related image? What if the category itself changes its name? Then all files of that category should be renamed?

Comment: For now let's assume category won't change and category name also won't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `instance` parameter in the `file_rename` method, you can use it to find the category.
So your file_rename method could be like:

```
def file_rename(instance, filename):
    if instance.category.name == 'random':
        prefix = '1'
    else:
        prefix = '2'
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    count = Count.objects.get(pk=1)
    ZSN = prefix + str(count.jeans_count + 1)
    filename = '{}.{}'.format(ZSN, ext)
    return os.path.join('images', filename)
```